# Why would form validation removes a simple string?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm having trouble when trying to validate a basic ModelForm instanciated with a QueryDict. The form has a field 'name' and when it goes through form.cleaned_data its value is removed, even when I submit something like "abc" as name. Consequently, I cant validate the form. I'm a bit used to Django and it's the first time I face such an issue.

Below are the corresponding lines in my view.

```
    elif elem_type == 'AP':
        form = ApplicabiliteForm(QueryDict(request.POST.get('form')), prefix='AP')
```

What is actually weird is that I can see "abc" in form['data'], I've already checked if it wasnt a problem of min/max_length or this kind of thing. Moreover, when I try `ApplicabiliteForm(QueryDict(request.POST.get('form')), prefix='AP').is_valid()` in debugger it returns true.

Any help will be appreciated, it's actually blowing my mind ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's submitted as a JSON string, so it deserializes the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `form.data` shows `{'name': 'abc'}` because that's the data you passed in. It doesn't mean that it's the correct key.

If the form has `prefix='AP', then the key for the name field should be 'AP-name', not`name`.

Finally, if the `name` field is not required, and `AP-name` is missing, then the field value will be set to `''` and the form will still be valid.

Comment: God I feel so dumb, indeed I forgot to include prefix in my form instance. Thanks !